# javascript , Innerhtml information to php mail

Tags: javascript, email, innerhtml, php

i have made this simple shopping cart, where the added products gets displayed via innerhtml, now i want this innerhtml information to be displayed in the mail that gets sent when you submit. The way i've done it so far is that every value input is submitted into the mail, that meanns all the 70 products are added in the mail regardless if they are empty or not(i only want the ones that are not empty to show in the mail)

http://www.premiere-produkter.no/pp/lagersalg/index.php is the link for the web page,

Part of the javascript:

```
if (document.form.prod73.value >=1) {
myArray[73] =  "Fleecejakke EN471 Orange XXL" + " " +  document.form.prod73.value + "<br>";
} 
else if(document.form.prod73.value <=0) {
    myArray[73] = "";
}



var len = myArray.length;
for (var i=0; i<len != "0" !=""; ++i)
{
//function adding() {   
radioAlert.innerHTML = (myArray + "<br>").replace (/,/g, '');
+ myfunc();
//}
return false;
}
```

the php part (cept the headers,recipients and so on that goes with the mail)
     $body = "

```
Bekreftelse på bestilling:
\r\n\r\n 

Navn: $name_field\r\n 
===========================================
E-Mail: $email_field\r\n 
===========================================
Firma: $firma\r\n 
===========================================
Adresse: $adresse\r\n 
===========================================
Poststed: $poststed\r\n 
===========================================
Postnummer: $postnummer\r\n 
===========================================
Firma: $firma\r\n 
===========================================
Telefon: $tlf\r\n 
===========================================
Message: $message\r\n\r\n
=====================================================================================
Takk for at du bestilte hos oss, orderen din vil sett på og du vil motta en faktura snart. 
\r\n\r\n
=====================================================================================
Varebestillingen : 
$varer
\r\n\r\n
===========================================
Total Order Sum: $order kr
===========================================
";




if (mail($recipients,$subject, $body, $header)) {
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, Are you trying to submit input which are not empty?

Comment: Yeah sorry for my bad writing today, not thinking clearly today.

Comment: Yeah sorry for my bad writing today, not thinking clearly today.
but yeah if you add product 73(vare73) the information shows up in a box via javascript,via innerhtml, i want only the objects chosen to appear in the mail, not all the empty ones which i have now im my temporary solution where i've added all of the inputs in the php

Comment: Never mind i managed to finally do this purely with php^^

Answer (score 0):

The answer was probably not the easiest way but it is the safest by just not doing what i first asked for, i just did a simple if and else php command where if prod 1,2,3,4 was over or similar to 1 a variable that i called in the body of the mail changed its content. If it wasnt over one it was just empty, thats the way i found that worked atleast, probably some easier ways but atleast this is working smoothly ^^

```
//pilotjakke grå//
$vare1 = $_POST['prod5']; 
$vare2 = $_POST['prod6']; 
$vare3 = $_POST['prod7']; 
$vare4 = $_POST['prod8']; 
$vare5 = $_POST['prod9']; 
$varesum1 = $_POST['smu']; 

    if(isset
    ($_POST['prod5']) 
    || ($_POST['prod6'] )
    || ($_POST['prod7'] ) 
    || ($_POST['prod8'] )   
    || ($_POST['prod9'])) 
    {
    if ($_POST['prod5'] || $_POST['prod6'] || $_POST['prod7'] || $_POST['prod8'] || $_POST['prod9'] >=1 ) 
    {

    $pilotjakkegrå=
    "\n Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå Small: $vare1\r\n 
    Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå Medium: $vare2\r\n
    Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå Large: $vare3\r\n
    Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå X-Large: $vare4\r\n
    Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå XX-Large: $vare5\r\n
    Pris per enhet: 349 kr\r\n
    Total sum for Pilotjakke pelsforet Grå: $varesum1 kr\r\n
    ";
    }

    else
        {
        $pilotjakkegrå= "";
        }
     };
```